# Can't upload build to TestFlight (Application Loader Error)

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight, iosdeployment

Using Xamarin.Forms, we have developed the app on Visual Studio for Mac.

All pre-requisites are met(such as setting up all from PP to iTunes Connect etc.)

The signing of the .ipa file is successful. However, the following error is observed in the following screenshot:

[image]

Hence we are unable to upload the build to TestFlight. All help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As the error says check your app icon image set, it’s missing the “120x120” app icon image, or, if you have already added it, probably it is not in the correct format.

Comment: I don't know a lot about Xamarin but hope it will help [Missing required file icon](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/71397/missing-required-file-icon-error-itms-90022-itms-90023). To create icons set I use the app [Icon Set Creator](https://itunes.apple.com/app/icon-set-creator/id939343785).